# How to create custom UI controls for metaplex

Tags: react

I'm having difficulty getting WalletMultiButton and WalletDisconnectButton exactly the way I want it. Is it possible to create my own buttons? This is for React

Comment: If you have the time to down vote why not actually try helping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This repo should definitely help - https://github.com/Fulgurus/candy-machine-v2-responsive-ui

Production ready Candy Machine V2 Responsive UI which can be easily customised in less than 5 mins.

It also has One-Click Vercel Deployment.